# Using Javascript to access PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php

How can I access `PHP` variables from `Javascript` where the `PHP` code exists in a separate file?

The code I have is:

```
<?php
$res = "OK";
?>

<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunc() 
   {
      res = <?php echo json_encode($res); ?>;
      console.log("res = " + res);
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="myFunc()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if I were to move my `php` code to a separate file called `a.php`, how can I access `$res`? Assume I am calling `a.php` with a `GET` request (`XMLHttpRequest` object).

Comment: enclose it in quotes.. `res = '<?php echo json_encode($res); ?>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try-

```
res = "<?php echo json_encode($res); ?>";
```

Comment: That does not work. If I do `console.log(res);` after the above statement, `res` is output as "<?php echo json_encode($res); ?>".

Comment: You file must be a `.php`. Is it?

Comment: After removal of all `php` code to `a.php`, there is nothing left except `javascript` and `html`. Does the file still need to be renamed to .php?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to say; but - if you are using `<?php ?>` in a file that file must be a `.php` file- that's it!